# Add a feature to follow a user (maybe in a particular tag)

Tags: discussion, feature-request

What do you think about if in Stack Overflow there was the possibility to follow your favorite users? Something similar to Twitter where in a particular page on the site you can see the activity of the users that you think will give very useful answers (or questions).

I think it would be a good thing to give the opportunity to the newly registered users to create a small network of users and, at the same time increase further the popularity of "famous" users.

In this case when some user gives me a very nice answer I could decide to follow him or her to see other answers, maybe in a particular tag.

For example I want to decide to follow xxx user on yyy tag.

If you disagree, would you say why?

Comment: Repeat after me: Stack Overflow is *not* a social network.

Comment: That said, each user profile has a RSS feed linked; use your favourite RSS reader to follow users through that.

Comment: I am just asking for an opinion...

Comment: And I am giving it. Stack Overflow is not a social network. We focus on the content here. That we need users to provide the content is an inconvenient necessity, really.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I think that should be an opportunity to show faster some helpful answer or question

Comment: I don't want this as first page or activity.. just a feature that if you want you can activate

Comment: No, we already have other features for that: hot questions, per-tag hot answers, etc.

Comment: The problem with new features like this is that it takes a lot of effort to build, so you need to come up with something more than 'just a feature that'd be nice'.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I hate socialnetworks... I every day ask myself how you might improve.. maybe the answer for my answer is "No at all"

Comment: Multidupe. And we barely survived facebook.stackoverflow.com.

Comment: @mkross1983 I did not expect so much rage sincerely .. I did not want to compare SO to a socialnetwork... I just was wondering if it could be  interesting for other users

Comment: You survived @Will? You mean you were _always_ like this?! :-)

Comment: Rage? There is rage here?

Comment: @jayblanchard my english is very poor. I don't want to be offensive..

Comment: As I was reading this @faby I saw no rage or viciousness.

Comment: @JayBlanchard I think that firsts up or down vote makes the difference.. If firsts comments are negatives so other users probably continue to downvoting and vice versa. Don't you agree? I think that if this feature will be implemented tons of users benefit of its advantages

Comment: I don't think so. Set up the feeds for the folks you want to follow and you'll be good to go.

Comment: @JayBlanchard  thanks  for your attention

Comment: Downvoting is not "aggressive". It is normal practice. Questions on Meta are regularly downvoted by people who disagree with your proposal. *Especially* when they are feature requests. If you were saying that my comment is aggressive, well maybe. It gets tiring to read proposals like this *ad nauseum*, and it gets even more tiring to hear people who insist on posting them whining about their being unpopular and attracting downvotes.

Comment: RSS is not very useful to me personally, my RSS reader has a lot more feeds other than technology. having my own "newsfeed" here in Stack Overflow that highlights what my favorite/most knowledgeable authors are up to will help me concentrate better.

Comment: I understand people here are afraid of turning SO in some sort of popularity contest with followers and so on. If you ever decided to implement this feature you can simply omit the parts of it that introduce biased judgements, i.e: showing the number of followers on each user's profile, having a "friends" list such that you can be affected in your judgements by what your friends follow, etc..

Comment: In short this feature can be very useful on a personal level for each user to see where they stand in terms of knowledge compared to people they know or their peers. And whether we like it or not, we will always rate people's level of knowledge on any subject so I just want to "bookmark" those people whose knowledge/opinion i appreciate the most. this will be even more useful in other parts of the network that are of a subjective nature like philosophy and so on. Sort of the same way Quora works.

Comment: What if users could only follow other users anonymously? IE, users would not even know how many followers they have and have everything completely anonymous. There are times when I think it might be useful to have this feature especially if you have a colleague that you want to follow or a friend.

Comment: @MartijnPieters this would be more than nice. It would be an educational feature. Some users have tremendous knowledge, you should have a mechanism, like favorites, to be notified when a user posts an answer. So you can LEARN. This has nothing to do with popularity, or being a Social Network. I personally just got done reading an excellent answer by a very high rep user and thought, man i love reading this guys answers...which brought me here. **It would be educational to be notified when he posts an answer**. Want to stop if from being social, keep followers and follows secret.

Comment: @DanBeaulieu: you can already do that. You can use the RSS feed, as shown in Fish Below the Ice's answer. But if you wanted to learn a new language, why limit yourself to one user? Pick out all the top answers in the tag. There is also a hot answers tab per tag, where you can read very recent great answers.

Comment: @MartijnPieters nobody ever said it would be just one user, I've been following my tag of choice long enough to know whose answers I can count on to be of very high quality. I assume the "top answers" are based on votes, votes are definitely not an indicator of a great, informative answer. I've seen pretty lame answers get more than 5 votes, I'd still be sifting to find good content. Again, this isn't a feature that would just "be nice", it would probably pull me back into the app or website more frequently than anything else. Anyway, I'll check out the RSS feed option, thanks for your time.

Comment: The last comment in this thread is almost 2 years old. Official stand is still the same?

Comment: Couple years later, now that emotions hopefully are a bit lower: I'm not satisfied with "not a social network" answer. It sorta is, since the "teams" era. Besides, I may want to follow an user for many non-social reasons. I may want to keep track of him, because I recognise that he may have nice ideas or he will develop to be someone I'd like to hire. (continued)

Comment: I may simply want to keep track of a bunch of new contributors that I can guide at asking questions and take care of their posts. I may want to keep track of someone I think is working through a personal project and I recognise his struggles. I may want to keep an eye on a new contributor without questions, but with a lot of answers. This doesn't make SO social network. This feature still can be used for community reasons. (community != social; SO is a community, but isn't social).

Answer (score 24):

There *is* an RSS feed for any user you'd like to follow. For example:

https://stackoverflow.com/feeds/user/22656

You can find the "User Feed" link at the bottom right of any user profile. Now you can use your favorite RSS newsreader/consumer.

See also: [A "friends list" on Stack Overflow would be nice](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/886/a-friends-list-on-stack-overflow-would-be-nice)

Comment: Yes I was asking something similar to this feature but inside SO and with the possibility to filter only some tag. If my friend is a genius in c# and java i would be able to "follow" c# answer of my friend in a web page.. Thanks for attention

Comment: You might want to search on [meta.se]. This "feature" has been requested multiple times and fairly emphatically answered in the negative each time.

Comment: @FishBelowtheIce this shows that users are still unconvinced of the reasons SO moderators give for refusing to implement this :)

Comment: You do suggest a viable solution.. but, not everyone has a "favorite RSS newsreader/consumer." ;) I would rather wish the feature gets accepted by SO.

Answer (score 3):

The short answer is no.  SE isn't a social network, it doesn't want to be a social network.

You're a C#/JavaScript guy; why not create a Firefox/chrome add-in that allows you to save the URL of user profiles?  Or, you can write a script that will allow you to view all the questions for a user?

Just run this over at https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/new

```
Select * from (
select
    u.DisplayName,
    'Answer' as [Post Type],
    q.Body as [Post],
    q.Score,
    q.CreationDate
from
    Posts q
  left join 
    Users u
  on q.OwnerUserID = u.Id  
where
      q.CommunityOwnedDate is null
  and q.OwnerUserId = 2174085
  and q.postTypeId = 2
  
  UNION ALL
  
  select
    u.DisplayName,
    'Question' as [Post Type],
    q.Title as [Post],
    q.Score,
    q.CreationDate
from
    Posts q
  left join 
    Users u
  on q.OwnerUserID = u.Id  
where
      q.CommunityOwnedDate is null
  and q.OwnerUserId = 2174085
  and q.postTypeId = 1
  ) D
  order by CreationDate
```

The userID is mine, so just change it to whomever you're interested in following.  You can even tweak the script to only look in certain tags, for a certain date range, etc...

Comment: Is tag subscribing that different to subscribing to a  question?

Comment: @DarkTrick - This is actually subscribing to a *user*, to some degree.